# Does using GitHub Pages affect your SEO?

Tags: seo, github

Would my site's SEO be impacted if I used GitHub pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. From an SEO standpoint, GitHub Pages is not special compared to any other web host.

If you choose the default which is to host your website on a `github.io` subdomain, Google is likely to consider your site's SEO separately from the sites that live on the other `github.io` subdomains, because it should be obvious to the algorithm that they are different websites run by different content publishers.

If you use your own custom domain, whether you use GitHub Pages or another web host, Google will naturally consider your site's SEO separately from other websites.

Either way, your choice to use or not use GitHub Pages should not affect your site's SEO. If your website uses a custom domain, then in addition, its SEO should not be affected in any way by migrating to or away from GitHub Pages as long as the site keeps the same URL.